# Parse variables to a scheduledjob in powershell

Tags: powershell, automation

Im trying to create a script who will remove an AD-User from a group when the time is reached.
It works very well if i remove de schedule lines. And it also schedule the job. But, when the date and time is reached the job cant remove de ad-user. After reading the Results.xml file i was able to understand that, when the script run, the variables who contains the user and group information is null... Is there a way to save a file inside de register-schedulejob context?
Or, maybe, save the inputs information to a file and load then into the task... Im really confused of how to do that.

The problem there i want to solve with this script is very simple. I want to remove ad users from specific group when the date is reached. It would be nice if i can run this script from any pc of my teammates.

```
#Reading input
$dateStr = Read-Host("Data (dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss)")
$date = [DateTime]::ParseExact($dateStr, 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss', $null)

$user = Read-Host("User ")
Write-Host "[1]-Parvi_PS_VPN_Portal`n[2]-Parvi_PS_VPN_Forticlient"
$groupOption = Read-Host("To which group user will be added")

#UserGroup options
if($groupOption -eq '1'){
    $group = 'Parvi_PS_VPN_Portal'
}elseif ($groupOption -eq 2) {
    $group = 'Parvi_PS_VPN_Forticlient'
}else {
    Write-Host "Invalid Option"
}

#Job creation
$trigger = New-JobTrigger -Once -At $date
$jobOption = New-ScheduledJobOption -RunElevated -RequireNetwork
$credential = Get-Credential
$creationDate = Get-Date -Format "dd_mm_yyyy_hh_mm_ss"

Register-ScheduledJob -Name "${user}_${group}_${creationDate}" -Trigger $trigger -Credential $credential -scriptblock {
    Remove-ADGroup -Identity $group -Members $user 
} -ScheduledJobOption $jobOption
```

Nothing. Im stuck of how to do that.

Comment: 1) You ask to which group the user should be ADDED, but the script is meant to REMOVE the user from the group. 2) After a Read-Host, you should always check if what the user entered is correct/workable and in your case, even after an "Invalid Option", the script goes on trying to create a scheduled action..

Comment: [`Register-ScheduledJob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psscheduledjob/register-scheduledjob) has an `-ArgumentList` parameter, which you must use to pass any values from the caller's scope to the script block to be executed by the scheduled job.